# preg_match_all query to only display the outer group having issues

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I can't work out how to only show the outer group level of a preg query, I'll give you the example.

```
preg_match_all('/start(.*?)end/', $input, $matches);
```

This input `start1 start2 2end 1end` produces this output `start1 start2 2end`.

As you can see it doesn't group properly - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to make the dot in `.*` *greedy*, rather than lazy.  As an example:

```php
$input = "blah blah start1 hello start2 blah 2end 1end";
preg_match_all('/start(.*)end/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0][0]);
```

This prints:

```
start1 hello start2 blah 2end 1end
```